# Date calculations without daylight savings time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate, dst, nstimezone

I'm trying to perform date calculations for a scheduling app but am running into issues with daylight savings time.  I'm trying to determine the number of days between two dates with:

```
NSDateComponents *activityComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
activityComponents = [self.calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                      fromDate:self.viewBeginDate
                                        toDate:item.ES
                                       options:0];
NSLog(@"Days: %d and hours: %d", [activityComponents day], [activityComponents hour]);
```

where `self.viewBeginDate` and `item.ES` are both NSDate objects and `self.calendar` is a gregorian calendar.

- When calculating between Nov 1, 2013 and Nov 1, 2013, it provides 0.
- When calculating between Nov 1, 2013 and Nov 2, 2013, it provides 1.
- When calculating between Nov 1, 2013 and Nov 3, 2013, it provides 2.
- When calculating between Nov 1, 2013 and Nov 4, 2013, it provides 2
  again!

Here is my output:

```
    Days: 0 and hours: 0
    Days: 1 and hours: 0
    Days: 2 and hours: 0
    Days: 2 and hours: 24
    Days: 3 and hours: 23
```

I'd like to be able to determine the number of days between 2 `NSDate` objects without impact by Daylight Savings Time, as my app doesn't care what local or timezone the user is in.  I just want it to tell me that there are 3 days between Nov 1, 2013 and Nov 4, 2013.  Any thoughts?

My `NSDate` objects are created from strings in the format of: 2013-11-01 00:00:00 +0000.  Each date has the time set to 00:00:00 with the GMT offset of +0000.

I've thought of two possible options:

- Use `isDaylightSavingTime` to check each date and create a new (modified) date offset by 1 hour if it the date is Daylight Savings Time.  I'm worried about the added calculation time as my app calculates the date between a given begin date and an array of other dates.  This array may have up to 2,000 dates in it.  I'm not sure if that's a legit concern or not...
- create a custom timezone that is not affected by DST.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Just set your NSCalendar to UTC.

Comment: I've changed my calendar to UTC with no difference in the results.  Did I do this right? `[self.calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];`

Comment: I've listed out the timezones with `NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]);` and got a long list in the likes of "America/such-and-such" and "Europe/such-and-such" and even GMT, but I didn't see UTC.  Is it not always available?

Comment: Use GMT, it is the old name for UTC. I am amazed that Apple does not add UTC.

Comment: @Zaph: Apple relies on the ICU libraries for its date and time stuff, and [they don't bother with the distinction either](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone).

Comment: Or just use `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm your observations using dates around the 27 October (when British Summer Time started) and setting the time zone to Europe/London. The "n days 24 hours" seems to be a quirk (kind word for a bug, somebody forgot to carry).

Solution 1: Use an `NSCalendar` set to UTC. UTC has no daylight savings.

Solution 2: As all your times are at midnight and the maximum daylight savings shift is 1 hours then a "day" is between 23 and 25 hours. To allow for this, and handle the quirk at the same time simply:

```
daysBetween = [activityComponents day] + ([activityComponents hour] >= 23 ? 1 : 0);
```

Note that this *only* works because time is the same in the two dates!

Comment: It worked; I set the `NSCalendar` to UTC with `[self.calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];`  I wasn't getting UTC to work earlier because I was mistakenly trying to set the timezone before I initialized the calendar.  Once I moved it to after the alloc,init bit it worked fine.  Thanks all for your help!